# loading the `folding` mode with `use-package`

Tags: use-package, code-folding

I am using the [folding minor mode](https://melpa.org/#/folding) in Emacs which I get installed with the following `use-package` macro:

```
(use-package folding
  :ensure t)
```

The above works and ensures that `folding` is installed whenever I fire up Emacs. However, when I visit a buffer with the folded marks ( `// {{{` and `// }}}`), the minor mode is not automatically loaded and I have to load it explicitly with:

```
M-x folding-mode
```

I looked up the [documentation](https://melpa.org/#/folding) and saw that for the Folding mode to start automatically when a folded file is loaded you need to do this:

```
(if (load "folding" 'nomessage 'noerror)
         (folding-mode-add-find-file-hook))
```

However, changing my `use-package` macro to the following:

```
(use-package folding
  :ensure t
  :config
  (if (load "folding" 'nomessage 'noerror)
      (folding-mode-add-find-file-hook))
  )
```

… makes no difference. I still have to load folding mode manually with `M-x folding-mode`. What gives?

## update

Turns out that in addition to the accepted answer, I also had to add an [Emacs file variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) at the end of the file:

```
// {{{ folding-mode

// Local Variables:
// folded-file: t
// End:

// }}}
```

But adding this editor-specific markup in every source file is too much for me. Is there a way to automatically always activate `folding-mode` when visiting a buffer?

I have tried

```
(use-package folding
   :ensure t
   :config
     (folding-mode))
```

… and:

```
(use-package folding
   :ensure t
   :config
     (setq 'folding-mode t))
```

… but none of the above is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
(use-package folding
  :ensure t
  :config
  (folding-mode-add-find-file-hook))
```

As to why, the

```
if (load "folding" 'nomessage 'noerror)
```

bit is really saying "try and load this package, and if it works invoke the next command" (see help for `load`). You take care of that using `use-package` already, so you just need to call the next command directly in `:config`.

Edit:

Based on the update, try something like this:

```
(use-package folding
  :ensure t
  :config
  (folding-install-hooks)
  (defun my-always-fold ()
    (setq-local folded-file t))
  (advice-add #'folding-mode-find-file :before #'my-always-fold))
```

That seems to work in my tests.

Comment: I tried that. Makes no difference. Having that in my `.emacs` and loading a file with `// {{{` markings and then doing `C-h v folding-mode` reports that the value of the `folding-mode` is `nil`. I still have to do `M-x folding-mode` to activate it.

Comment: See updated question. Is there a way to enter `folding-mode` without having to set the Emacs file variable `folded-file` at the end of each file?

Comment: the updated `use-package` incantation worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(use-package folding
  :ensure t
  :init
  (folding-mode-add-find-file-hook))
```

It seems that you want to only load folding-mode the first time you visit a folded file, but the hook that detects whether a file is folded is in the folding-mode package! This of course is impossible, you'll have to uncoditionally load folding-mode as above.

You may prefer to stick with:

```
(use-package folding
  :ensure t
  :config
  (folding-mode-add-find-file-hook))
```

It's not as bad you might think: it's true that on the very first folded file you open in a given session you'll have to manually run `M-x folding-mode`, but then the hook gets installed and any other folded file you open will get detected and put in folding-mode.